# git svn fetch with jgit

Tags: git, git-svn, jgit

I use jGit to automate my interactions with git on my projects. There is an API corresponding to `git fetch` but I need here to execute `git svn fetch` and could not find anything about svn in the jGit project [javadoc](http://jgit.info/javadoc/).

So I am afraid it is not possible but maybe there is a trick to achieve this, any idea how to?

My alternative is to call the shell command `git svn fetch` but its a lot less clean than using jGit so I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

There're some features that JGit doesn't support, and SVN integration is among them. I doubt that JGit will ever support SVN integration because of several reasons (absence of required SVN API, licensing policy and so on).

As a workaround, if you have access to the Subversion repository, you may install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your SVN repository (it will create a Git interface for it) and use Git interface created reusing your common workflow.

See also the full list of [JGit/EGit to Git differences](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Differences_to_Git) and the related [bug-entry](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315264).